# Send javascript array object to ashx

Tags: javascript, arrays, vb.net, handler

I have an array of objects in javascript and I like to send this object to the server in a post request to ashx handler

I'm sending the information with this script:

```
var filtersArray = [{id:1, val:"filter1"}, {id:2, val:"filter2"}];
var object = {filters: filtersArray, id: 123, name: "object"};
$.post('handler.ashx', jQuery.param(object), function () {
    //do some stuff
});
```

I can see in the chrome console the network params

```
Form Data
    filters[0][id]:1
    filters[0][val]:filter1
    filters[1][id]:2
    filters[1][val]:filter2
    id:123
    name:object
```

And in the handler I want to retrieve the parameter filter as an array, list or something.
I tried to do this: `context.Request("filters[]")` but the response is `Nothing` to retrieve the value I have to `context.Request("filters[0][id]")`
But this is not useful because the size of the list could be different in each request and with this solution I should have to add a parameter with the size and iterate parameters with this number.

Another option will be transfor to a JSON object and later deserialize the object in the server. But I prefer to not do that.

There is any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure of a solution, but if you set a breakpoint you can add a watch on the entire request object and see everything.  Also, not sure if you need to use `Request.Form` or not.  But I would recommend looking through all the properties of the request object and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: When I see the variables in the Request.Form the name of the parameters that I see are the same as the console in chrome.
`filters[0][id]` `filters[0][val]` ...

Comment: What I would recommend doing is using stringify to pass the object as a string, then you can deserialize it when it gets to the server.